# Starting a new Activity from View, and then closing the View

Tags: android, android-activity, android-view

I have 3 activities: `Menu`, `Game`, `Resetscreen`.

In `Menu`, if I click a button, I create a new `Game`.

`Game` creates a `View` called `GameView`, and then sets that as it's content view (obviously).

`GameView` draws a lot of stuff, assisted by a `Movement` class (it supplies `GameView` with e.g. the X and Y coordinates of a circle). Its `onDraw()` invalidates itself after having drawn everything, creating an `Animation` as smooth as possible. Its `onTouchEvent()` can (depending on when the user clicked) either do nothing and let the game continue to run or (**and that's where the problem is**) close the `Game` activity (and therefore itself?) and start the activity `Resetscreen`.

`Resetscreen` should then be able to create a new `Game` activity with a new `GameView` and restart the Game.

The problem is, it doesn't seem to properly terminate anything. The first run is smooth. From then on, it goes slow quickly, even on a brand new HTC M8 (not even talking about the slow emulator).

I'd like to know if somebody could supply me with a standard setup of a game with a view and how changing between activities occurs.

Edit:

Go from `Menu` to `Game` (and therefore use `GameView`) and from that to `Resetscreen` and, on button press to:

- a new `Game` activity and `GameView`, or
- the old one

Comment: why dont you use fragments for the gameview? and also if gameview is in a viewgroup, in the game activity, there is a function called removeView() for viewgroups..try that and see..  (did i understand your queston well??)

Comment: I think not. But Using a fragment would be an idea, yes. And no, the view isn't in a view group. the "view" is basically the Gameview class that extends View.

Comment: You should probably delegate a listener from `GameView` to the `Game` activity. That way, you can control the flow from the activity itself.

Comment: How are you closing the Game activity? Some code would be nice.